Errors occuring related to Local Storage (JS)
I have been working on (Task-List) project using JS. I am experiencing an error related to JS.
Error:
"The Local Storage is storing an empty (null) string in an array, although it is storing a non-empty string (working fine) but for the empty string, i have set a condition in my code (pasted below) ."
The Code:
// Storing tags as variables

const text_input = document.getElementById('text');
const submit_input = document.getElementById('submit');
const filter_task = document.getElementById('filter-text');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-black');
const addedTasks = document.querySelector('.task-box');
const task_form = document.querySelector('.task-form');
const task_list = document.querySelector('.task-box-list');

// Event Listeners Execution
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',  taskFromLocalStorage);
task_form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
addedTasks.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clearTasks);
filter_task.addEventListener('keyup', filterTasks);

// Events Functions

// Retrive tasks from LS
function taskFromLocalStorage() {
    var taskInputValue = text_input.value;
    let tasks;
    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
        tasks = [];
    }
    else{
       tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }
    tasks.forEach(function(taskInputValue){
     // Create a particular div for every task
     const newDIV = document.createElement('div');
     newDIV.className = "task-box-item flex justify-between px-3 ";

     // Li tag (Task)
     var newTask = document.createElement('li');
     newTask.className = "task-list list-none text-l px-4 py-2";
     newTask.textContent = taskInputValue;

     // Delete a particular task (link)
     const deleteTask = document.createElement('a');
     deleteTask.className = "delete_task translate-y-[10px]";
     deleteTask.href = '#';
     
     // Delete a particular task (icon)
     const deleteIcon = document.createElement('i');
     deleteIcon.className = 'fa-solid fa-xmark fa-lg text-red-700';

     
     addedTasks.appendChild(newDIV);
     newDIV.appendChild(newTask);
     deleteTask.appendChild(deleteIcon);
     newDIV.appendChild(deleteTask);
    })
}

// Persist the tasks to store in Local Storage
function storeTaskInLocalStorage(task) {
    let tasks;
    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
        tasks = [];
    }
    else{
       tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }
    tasks.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('tasks' , JSON.stringify(tasks));
}
// Add Function
function addTask(e) {
    const taskInputValue = text_input.value;
    if (taskInputValue !== "") {
        // Create a particular div for every task
        const newDIV = document.createElement('div');
        newDIV.className = "task-box-item flex justify-between px-3 ";

        // Li tag (Task)
        var newTask = document.createElement('li');
        newTask.className = "task-list list-none text-l px-4 py-2";
        newTask.textContent = taskInputValue;

        // Delete a particular task (link)
        const deleteTask = document.createElement('a');
        deleteTask.className = "delete_task translate-y-[10px] h-full";
        deleteTask.href = '#';
        
        // Delete a particular task (icon)
        const deleteIcon = document.createElement('i');
        deleteIcon.className = 'fa-solid fa-xmark fa-lg text-red-700';

        
        addedTasks.appendChild(newDIV);
        newDIV.appendChild(newTask);
        deleteTask.appendChild(deleteIcon);
        newDIV.appendChild(deleteTask);
    }
    else{
        alert('Field empty! NO task added.');
        localStorage.removeItem(taskInputValue); 

    }
    // Set to LS
    storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInputValue);
    
    // Set text field to empty again
    text_input.value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
} 

I have taken help from ChatGPT but it doesn't work well for me in any way.

Are you able to share the unexpected array result you're receiving? I'm not sure what you mean by "empty (null) string in an array"

Only call storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInputValue) when taskInputValue !== "" (put it inside the existing if).  I don't think you need/want  localStorage.removeItem(taskInputValue) at all.

That doesn't look like a JavaScript error message to me. Is i have set a condition in my code (pasted below) really part of the error message (it's inside the quotes)?

localStorage has no restriction against storing empty strings. Where is this error really coming from?

The error is stemming from the addTask function. When taskInputValue is not an empty string, two actions are to be performed:

Render the new task on the screen.
Add the new task to localStorage.

You are performing only the first action inside your if check for empty string. The second action is currently performed outside the if else block, meaning taskInputValue will be added to localStorage regardless of whether it is a non-empty string or not. You need to move the code adding the task to localStorage inside your if check. The addTask function will look like this:
// Add Function
function addTask(e) {
    const taskInputValue = text_input.value;
    if (taskInputValue !== "") {
        // Create a particular div for every task
        const newDIV = document.createElement('div');
        newDIV.className = "task-box-item flex justify-between px-3 ";

        // Li tag (Task)
        var newTask = document.createElement('li');
        newTask.className = "task-list list-none text-l px-4 py-2";
        newTask.textContent = taskInputValue;

        // Delete a particular task (link)
        const deleteTask = document.createElement('a');
        deleteTask.className = "delete_task translate-y-[10px] h-full";
        deleteTask.href = '#';
        
        // Delete a particular task (icon)
        const deleteIcon = document.createElement('i');
        deleteIcon.className = 'fa-solid fa-xmark fa-lg text-red-700';

        
        addedTasks.appendChild(newDIV);
        newDIV.appendChild(newTask);
        deleteTask.appendChild(deleteIcon);
        newDIV.appendChild(deleteTask);

        // Set to LS
        storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInputValue);
    }
    else{
        alert('Field empty! NO task added.');
        localStorage.removeItem(taskInputValue); 

    }
    
    // Set text field to empty again
    text_input.value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
}

